# Timesheet calculation for employees on public holidays in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need help with setting up an Excel timesheet for monthly salary calculation.  I am using a free timesheet template I've got from the Internet, but I need a few more functions.

So the hourly salary rate is:
1.Regular Hours,   2.Overtime Hours(1.5x),   3.Public Holiday Hours(2x).

So I have this three column which combines into the grand total payout.

But I need the timesheet to be able to detect every Sunday of the month and other public holidays (eg. Christmas day) and list the hours worked on these days under the Public Holiday Hours column instead of Regular Hours or Overtime Hours.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is the Day of Week column stored as an Excel date or text?  Is the only missing piece the holidays?  What are you using as a basis for identifying holidays other than Sundays?  Do the holiday entries need to be entirely in only the holiday column?  For example, since they're 2X the regular rate, you could leave the regular hours in place and duplicate the amount in the Holiday column (like a premium add-on) if a holiday "test" was true.

Comment: [WORKDAY function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-function-f764a5b7-05fc-4494-9486-60d494efbf33): Returns a number that represents a date that is the indicated number of working days before or after a date (the starting date). Working days exclude weekends and any dates identified as holidays. Use WORKDAY to exclude weekends or holidays when you calculate invoice due dates, expected delivery times, or the number of days of work performed.

Comment: [Holidays](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/holidays.html) for US holidays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume column A is a real date value, formatted to show the day name as well. That can be done with a custom format of `DDD dd/mm`.

The holiday hours needs to determine whether column A is a Sunday. That can be done with the `WEEKDAY()` function, which returns `1` for a Sunday.

You also need to include public holidays, which Excel doesn't cater for natively because every country's holidays are different. You could set up a list of holidays on another sheet, and give that list a range name (say `Holidays`). Then, your calculation needs to determine whether the column A date occurs in that range. Use `VLOOKUP()`. `VLOOKUP` has a particular quirk in that it will return `#N/A` if a value is not found, so you need to need to test for the error.

Thus the day is a Sunday if `WEEKDAY(A13)=1` and a holiday if `VLOOKUP(A13,Holidays,1,FALSE)` is not an error.

Cell `I13` will need to contain a conditional which combines these two tests. You can simply add them together provided that your holiday list does not contain Sundays.

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A13)=1,F13,0) + IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A13,Holidays,1,FALSE)),0,F13)
```

Note that I've used `F13` here, total hours, as it's unlikely that holiday working will be eligible for overtime **and** holiday premium, and I suspect that overtime is a simple calculation of `TimeOut - TimeIn - Breaks - DailyTimeToWork` (which is a constant set elsewhere). As the question doesn't define precise business rules, you will almost certainly need to tweak these suggestions.